# proof check on complete residue system modulo n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

Claim: if $a_1,a_2,\dots a_n$ is a complete residue system modulo $n$. and $gcd(a,n)=1$, then $aa_1,aa_2,\dots,aa_n$ is also a complete residue system modulo $n$.

proof:

To claim that $aa_1,aa_2,\dots,aa_n$ is also a complete residue system modulo $n$ it suffices to show $aa_i\not\equiv aa_j\pmod{n}$ for $0\leq i<j\leq n-1$. We suppose on the contrary $aa_i\equiv aa_j\pmod{n}$ for $0\leq i<j\leq n-1$. Then by definition we have $aa_i-aa_j\equiv 0\pmod{n}$. Then $n|aa_i-aa_j$ which means $n|a(a_i-a_j)$. Since $\gcd(a,n)=1$ by Euclid's Lemma we have $n|a_i-a_j$. But then we have $a_i\equiv a_j\pmod{n}$. This is a contradiction to the definition of a complete residue system as no pair of elements are congruent modulo $n$. Therefore, $aa_i\not\equiv aa_j\pmod{n}$ for $0\leq i<j\leq n-1$. So, $aa_1,aa_2,\dots,aa_n$ is a complete residue system modulo $n$.

I am not sure if my conclusion is correct, or if I should say "Therefore $a_i\not\equiv a_j\pmod{n}...etc"$

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @AvenDesta Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: I think it's fine.